# An abelian, characteristically simple group is divisible (supposedly).

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, abelian-groups, divisible-groups

This is **Exercise 4.13** of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*. According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22characteristically+simple%22+%22abelian%22) and [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Characteristically%20simple%2C%20abelian%2C%20divisible%20&p=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

On page 69 of Roman's book, we have

> **Definition:** Let $G$ be a group. A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is *characteristic* in $G$ if it is invariant under all automorphisms of $G$.

Write this as $H\sqsubseteq G$.

On page 121 *ibid.*, there is the

> **Definition:** A nontrivial group $G$ is *characteristically simple* if it has no proper characteristic subgroups.

On page 145, the exercise in question starts out as follows:

> An abelian group $A$ (written additively) is *divisible* if for any $a\in A$ and any positive integer $n$, there is a $b\in A$ for which $nb=a$.

### The Question:

> Prove that a characteristically simple abelian group $A$ is divisible.

### Thoughts:

Let $A$ be a characteristically simple abelian group.

Such a group is classified in the first $\blacktriangleright$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3160435/104041) by @YCor. No justification is given. (I would appreciate a reference to this end, please.)

Let $\varphi \in {\rm Aut}(A)$. Then, for any $B\sqsubseteq A$, either $B$ is trivial or $B=A$, and $\varphi(B)=B$ by definition.

Let $a\in A$. I aim to show that there for all $n\in \Bbb N$, there is some $b\in A$ with $nb=a$.

(I have nothing nontrivial to add.)

Please help :)

Comment: Isn't $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ characteristically simple, but not divisible?

Comment: Huh. That's odd. Thank you, @HagenvonEitzen. I wonder what Roman intended to set as an exercise then . . .

Comment: A finite group (abelian or nonabelian) is characteristically simple if and only if it is isomorphic to the directpower $S^k$ for some $k \ge 0$, where $S$ is s (abelian or nonabelian) finite simple group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every abelian group $A$ has a canonical collection of characteric subgroups $nA = \{ na : a \in A \}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ given by the $n^{th}$ powers. If $A$ is characteristically simple, these subgroups must each be either the entire group $A$ or the trivial subgroup $0$. So we split into two cases:

- If $nA = 0$ for some $n \ge 2$ then we must have $pA = 0$ for some prime divisor $p \mid n$ (otherwise, if $pA = A$ for all $p \mid n$ then we would have $nA = A$), so $A$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space. I'll leave it as an exercise to check that every $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space is characteristically simple (the basic idea is that the automorphism group acts transitively on subspaces of a fixed dimension, so no proper subgroups are characteristic). In particular, the exercise is false as stated.
- If $nA = A$ for all $n$ then $A$ is divisible. This is probably what the author had in mind.

In the divisible case we can keep going with a second source of characteristic subgroups: the $n$-torsion subgroups $\sqrt[n]{A} = \{ a \in A : na = 0 \}$ (this is not standard notation; I think $A[n]$ might be standard, but that notation is already too overloaded for my taste) are characteristic, so again must satisfy either $\sqrt[n]{A} = A$ or $\sqrt[n]{A} = 0$. If $\sqrt[n]{A} = A$ then every element is $n$-torsion so $nA = 0$ and $A$ can't be divisible. So we conclude that $\sqrt[n]{A} = 0$ for every $n$, hence that $A$ is torsion-free. Torsion-free divisible abelian groups are precisely vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ (divisibility allows us to define division and torsion-freeness guarantees that the result is unique), and it's again an exercise to show that $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces are characteristically simple.

This proves YCor's classification. He singles out the zero abelian group because it's both the zero $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space for any $p$ and the zero $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space; it is the unique group which satisfies $A = 0$ so it's an edge case for every case of this argument. In particular it's the unique group which is both torsion-free and torsion!

---

Note that $nA = \text{im} \left( A \xrightarrow{n} A \right)$ while $\sqrt[n]{A} = \text{ker} \left( A \xrightarrow{n} A \right)$. So their characteristic nature comes from an even stronger property of the multiplication-by-$n$ endomorphism on an abelian group, which is that it's [*natural*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) (commutes with arbitrary homomorphisms of abelian groups); formally, it's a natural transformation from the identity functor $\text{id}_{\text{Ab}} : \text{Ab} \to \text{Ab}$ to itself. It's a nice exercise to show that every such natural transformation has this form; in other words, $\text{End}(\text{id}_{\text{Ab}}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ (as rings, even).

This naturality property shows that $nA$ and $\sqrt[n]{A}$ have a property stronger than being characteristic: they are *natural subgroups*, in that arbitrary homomorphisms $f : A \to B$ induce homomorphisms $nA \to nB$ and $\sqrt[n]{A} \to \sqrt[n]{B}$. Formally, they are both [subfunctors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfunctor) of the identity functor, and as subfunctors can can be defined as the kernel resp. the image of multiplication-by-$n$ as a natural transformation.