# Let $G$ be f.g. with $H\le G$ s.t. $[G:H]<\infty$. Then $\exists K\le H$ with $K\sqsubseteq G$ and $[G:K]<\infty$.

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, characteristic-subgroups

This is **Exercise 4.29** of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Finitely%20generated%2C%20group%2C%20%24H%5Cle%20G%24%2C%20finite%20index%2C%20characteristic%20%2C%20%24K%5Cle%20H%24&p=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

> **Definition:** A subgroup $H\le G$ is *characteristic in $G$*, written $H\sqsubseteq G$,  when, for all $\sigma\in {\rm Aut}(G)$, we have $\sigma(H)=H$ (or, equivalently, $\sigma(H)\le H$).

### The Question:

> Let $G$ be a finitely-generated group with $H\le G$ such that $[G:H]<\infty$. Then there exists $K\le H$ characteristic in $G$ with $[G:K]<\infty$.

### Thoughts:

It is well-known that any finite index subgroup of a finitely-generated group is itself finitely-generated. Hence $H$ is finitely-generated. However, I don't recall this result in the book so far.

---

It might help to note that

$$[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$$

as cardinal numbers, once we have found a candidate for $K$. This is proven early on in the book.

---

A special case is when $K=H$. All we need to prove there is that $K$ is characteristic in $G$. There's nothing to say, though, that equality is always possible.

---

I have asked a question here on characteristic subgroups before: [An abelian, characteristically simple group is divisible (supposedly).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3943618/104041)

I have a few years of experience with combinatorial group theory, so, given that we're talking about finitely-generated groups, I feel as if I should be able to answer this; I guess my main difficulty is the property of being characteristic.

---

Please help :)

Comment: This reminds me of the result that a finite index subgroup always contains a finite index normal subgroup. Perhaps you can show that the number of distinct images of $H$ under the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is finite (here is, presumably, where finite generation would come into play) and then take their intersection? That intersection is certainly characteristic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ there is a unique subgroup $K$ of $H$ which is maximal with respect to the property of being characteristic in $G$: namely, it's the subgroup given by the intersection

$$K = \bigcap_{\varphi \in \text{Aut}(G)} \varphi(H)$$

of the images of $H$ under all automorphisms of $G$. So there exists a finite index characteristic subgroup iff $K$ is finite index.

As a warmup, here's an easier problem: it's a classic exercise to show that if $H$ is finite index in $G$ then there exists a subgroup $H'$ of $H$ which is *normal* and finite index in $G$. (We don't need $G$ to be finitely generated here.)  The proof is very short; the maximal such subgroup is the intersection $\bigcap_{g \in G} gHg^{-1}$ of the conjugates of $H$, and this subgroup is exactly the kernel of the action of $G$ on the cosets $G/H$, which is finite. We get the more precise statement that if $H$ has index $n$ then $H'$ can be chosen to have index dividing $n!$, and setting $G = S_n, H = S_{n-1}$ shows that this bound is tight.

We can try to imitate this construction. Instead of just considering the action of $G$ on $G/H$ let's consider the action of $G$ on $G/\varphi(H)$ for every automorphism $\varphi$. We are done if we can show that this construction produces finitely many isomorphism classes of $G$-sets. Here is where we need the hypothesis that $G$ is finitely generated: we can actually show more, namely

> **Proposition:** A finitely generated group $G$ has only finitely many isomorphism classes of actions on a finite set of size $n$.

*Proof.* There are finitely many homomorphisms $G \to S_n$. $\Box$

Translated back into subgroups this implies that $G$ has finitely many subgroups of a fixed finite index $n$, and since the subgroups $\varphi(H)$ all have the same index, in particular there are finitely many of these. So $K$ is the kernel of the action of $G$ on

$$\bigsqcup_{\varphi \in \text{Aut}(G)} G/\varphi(H)$$

which is finite, and we are done. More explicitly, if $G$ is generated by $r$ generators and $H$ has index $n$ then there are at most $n!^r$ homomorphisms $G \to S_n$, so the above set has size at most $n \cdot n!^r$, and $K$ has index dividing $(n \cdot n!^r)!$. Probably not best possible, but it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm missing something: I grant that there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of $G$-sets of order $n$; but how does imply that there are only finitely many subgroups of index $n$? Why can't distinct subgroups yield isomorphic $G$-sets?

Comment: @Shaun: Okay, I think this works: we may restrict to *normal* subgroups, by the usual result. Now suppose $H_1$ and $H_2$ are normal subgroups of finite index in $G$, and suppose $f\colon G/H_1\to G/H_2$ is an isomorphism of the $G$-sets under the usual action. Then for all $h\in H_1$,  $f(H_1) = f(hH_1) = hf(H_1)$, so $H_1$ fixes $f(H_1)$ in the action on $G/H_2$. But stabilizers of a point in $G/H_2$ are conjugates of $H_2$, which by assumption are all equal to $H_2$, so $H_1=H_2$.

Comment: @Arturo: a subgroup of index $n$ is the same thing as a pair consisting of a transitive $G$-set of order $n$ (there are finitely many isomorphism classes of these) and a choice of basepoint in this $G$-set (whose stabilizer is the desired subgroup), and there are $n$ choices of basepoint. This argument can be used to write down a generating function relating the number of homomorphisms $G \to S_n$ and the number of subgroups of index $n$, given here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376175/category-theory-and-arithmetical-identities/376223#376223

Comment: (I should clarify what I mean by "the same thing as." I mean the groupoid of pointed transitive $G$-sets of size $n$ is equivalent to the (discrete) groupoid of subgroups of index $n$. I don't mean that distinct points have distinct stabilizers; what I do mean is that points have the same stabilizer iff there's an automorphism of the $G$-set exchanging them.)