# Show that the identity component $G^\circ\sqsubseteq G$ (i.e., is characteristic) in a linear algebraic group $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-groups, noetherian, characteristic-subgroups

This is **Exercise 7.6.6** of Humphreys', *"Linear Algebraic Groups"*.

### The Question:

> Show that the identity component $G^\circ$ of a linear algebraic group $G$ is a characteristic subgroup.

### The Details:

The *identity component* is the unique irreducible component of $G$ of the identity $e$.

A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is *characteristic* if it is stable under all automorphisms $\varphi\in{\rm Aut}(G)$; that is, $\varphi(H)\subseteq H$.

### Thoughts:

I think we could make use of the following in Humphreys (paraphrased).

> **Proposition 7.3.1:** Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group. Then $G^\circ$ is a normal subgroup of finite index in $G$, whose cosets are the connected as well as irreducible components of $G$.

It takes care of showing $G^\circ$ is a subgroup.

One idea I have is to hit $G^\circ$ with an arbitrary $\varphi\in{\rm Aut}(G)$. The normality might come into play but I think the main thing to exploit would be irreducibility.

### Context:

For questions of mine involving irreducibility in the context of linear algebraic groups, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A104041+irreducible); you will find the definition of *irreducible* I am familiar with in those. The best such question for our current purposes is: [The components of a Noetherian space are its maximal irreducible closed subsets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4534592/104041)

Two questions of mine on characteristic subgroups of abstract groups are:

- [An abelian, characteristically simple group is divisible (supposedly).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3943618/104041)
- [Let $G$ be f.g. with $H\le G$ s.t. $[G:H]<\infty$. Then $\exists K\le H$ with $K\sqsubseteq G$ and $[G:K]<\infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3966048/104041)

---

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know $G^\circ\subset G$ is the *unique* irreducible component containing the identity $e$, then this is immediate.

Indeed, for any automorphism $\varphi$ of $G$, we have $\varphi(G^\circ)$ is also an irreducible component containing the identity $e$, so $\varphi(G^\circ)=G^\circ$ by uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was overthinking it.