# Prove that Q by addition can't be isomorpic to the direct product of two subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've already proved, that there are no non-trivial subgroups with a trivial intersection.

E.g. $H,G$ are subgroups in $F$, $\dfrac{a}{b} \in H$ and $\dfrac{c}{d} \in G$,
$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{a}{b}+...+\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{ab}{b} \in H,a \in H$
$a+a+...+a=ac \in H$.
Same for $c \in G$

I guess, I need to show, that if $F \simeq G \times H$ ,then there are $H_{1} \le H, G_{1} \le G: H_{1} \cap G_{1} = \{e\} $ and $H_{1} \simeq H,G_{1}  \simeq G$

No idea how to do it.

Comment: You've already proven it.  Intersecting trivially is part of being a direct product.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ the direct product of two non-trivial subgroups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278939/is-mathbbq-the-direct-product-of-two-non-trivial-subgroups)

Answer (score 0):

The statement should be that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not the direct product of two *proper* subgroups.

The idea is correct. If you have two nonzero subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ and take nonzero $x=a/b\in H_1$, $y=c/d\in H_2$, then you have
$$
z=bcx=ady\in H_1\cap H_2
$$
because subgroups are closed under multiples and clearly $z\ne0$.

Therefore no two nonzero subgroups intersect trivially and you're done.

Comment: How do I prove, that such subgroups with mentioned features exist though?

Comment: @A-grin Do you need to? If $\mathbb{Q}$ is the direct product of $K_1$ and $K_2$, then $K_1\cap K_2=\{0\}$ by definition, so by what we proved, one of them is the trivial subgroup.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, there is no definition for the direct product of subgroups in my course, only for the direct product for groups and as we know, groups can intersect non-trivially in the last case. So I can't use it.